# How to fix Typescript compilation error ts2345 "Type 'Response' is missing ... from type 'Response': redirected, trailer, formData!"

Tags: node.js, typescript, promise, node-fetch

I am trying to make a request using `node-fetch` in my typescript project and I do not understand how to fix the compilation error or what it actually tries to tell me.

I've updated all packages (including the global typescript package) to the latest versions.

I've created a gist that isolates the error: https://gist.github.com/HerrZatacke/ae90f608e042864b6e00e9c73a950602

This (very short) script is able to reproduce the compilation error:

```js
import fetch from 'node-fetch';

const toJson = (response: Response):PromiseLike<object> => (
  response.json()
);

const makeSomeRequest = (): Promise<object> => {
  return fetch('https://some-api.com/')
    .then(toJson)
};

makeSomeRequest();
```

The installed versions used are

```
@types/node-fetch 2.3.7
node-fetch2.6.0
typescript 3.5.2
```

the actual error is

```
example.ts:9:11 - error TS2345: Argument of type '(response: Response) => PromiseLike<object>' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: Response) => object | PromiseLike<object>'.
  Types of parameters 'response' and 'value' are incompatible.
    Type 'Response' is missing the following properties from type 'Response': redirected, trailer, formData
```

Comment: Looks like two different types with the same name `Response` to me.

Comment: Okay, sounds plausible.
As I am quite new to typescript, this is not meant to happen?

Comment: Typings for node-fetch `Response` doesn't have those 3 properties as you can see in the source code: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/29ca96dcfea1a0b3d07f0d4dda5445d8990f12dd/types/node-fetch/index.d.ts#L159 Why don't you use the native `Promise` type instead of `PromiseLike`?

Comment: Using `Promise` instead of `PromiseLike` unfortunately causes the same error

Answer (score 18, accepted):

With the help/hints of the two commenters above (thanks a lot), I managed to find the reason and a solution for that error:

Typescript initially tries to "guess" which types you are using.

The following line states I want to use the type [`response`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response), which is an interface of the native Fetch API

```js
const toJson = (response: Response): Promise<object> => {
```

the type definition for it can be found in [lib.dom.d.ts](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.dom.d.ts#L12300)

`node-fetch` instead is implementing it's own `Response` type from [@types\node-fetch\index.d.ts](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/node-fetch/index.d.ts#L159)

So, if the *correct* response type is being imported first, the typescript compiler runs without the error.

Which means, instead of just importing `node-fetch`, you also have to import it's definition of `Response`:

```js
import fetch, { Response } from 'node-fetch';
```